# What is the python code to load dataset from my hard disk

Tags: tensorflow

I try to learn machine learning from the [TensorFlow official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification).

But most tutorials do the download in command prompt.

I can't find any tutorial about loading my own image dataset from my own disk.

Would be great if you can give me a direct answer.

I put the image data set on my window 10 desktop:

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\DataSet\coins\data`

```
\test (label 1-211)

\train (label 1-211)

\validation (label 1-211)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory) for this where you just have to pass in the path to the files in the argument `directory`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=VALIDATION_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

test_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TEST_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

Comment: Found 6413 files belonging to 211 classes. It works , thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use flow_from_disk in keras.
here is a pretty good tutorial

[flow from disk in keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/)